# Replace an array element, if another is longer than it

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am trying to write a name checker, where the final output will output all names in an array, and a stat at the end that says how many characters the longest name in the array has. This is what I have so far. It doesn't work, though I don't know where to go from here.

```
var arrNameList = ['John', 'Lenny'];
var arrNameListLonger = [];

function addName() {
    var custname = document.getElementById('custname').value;
    arrNameList.push(custname);
}

function processArray() {
    var i = 0;
    var output = ('Total names in array is: ' + arrNameList.length + '<br />');
    while (i < arrNameList.length) {
        output += (arrNameList[i] + '<br />');
        if (arrNameList[i] > arrNameList[i + 1]) {
            arrNameListLonger[0] = (arrNameList[i]);
            output += ('The longest name in the array is ' + arrNameListLonger[0].length + ' characters');

        }
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
        i++;
    }
    return (output);
}
```

For comparison/guidance, here is the first stage of my code (it just outputs the names)

```
var arrNameList = ['John', 'Lenny'];

function addName() {
    var custname = document.getElementById('custname').value;
    arrNameList.push(custname);
}

function processArray() {
    var i = 0;
    var output = ('Total names in array is: ' + arrNameList.length + '<br />');
    while (i < arrNameList.length) {
        output += (arrNameList[i] + '<br />');
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
        i++;
    }
    return (output);
}
```

Comment: There's no need to wrap the right-hand side of assignments, etc., in `()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually comparing each name with the next name in the array. You are not even comparing the length of the strings.

To get the longest name, you need to have a variable that will hold this name. Init it with an empty string and compare this longestName with each name in your array. If it is longer, replace the variable with the current name.

---

- You don't have to use `()` to surround your right-hand side of the assignment
- You can use a simple `for` loop to iterate your array. You will have the condition to stop and the index on the same line
- You have a `return` statement that seems to be not necessary inside `processArray()`

```js
var arrNameList = ['John', 'Lenny'];
var arrNameListLonger = [];

function addName() {
  var custname = document.getElementById('custname').value;
  arrNameList.push(custname);
}

function processArray() {
  var longestName = '';
  var output = 'Total names in array is: ' + arrNameList.length + '<br />';
  for (var i = 0, l = arrNameList.length; i < l; i++) {
    output += arrNameList[i] + '<br/>';
    if(arrNameList[i].length > longestName.length){
      longestName = arrNameList[i];
    }
  }
  output += "The longest name is " + longestName;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
  return output;
}
```

```html
<input id="custname" />
<button onclick="addName()">Add</button>
<button onclick="processArray()">Process</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Here is another version of your code using `ES6`

```js
var arrNameList = ['John', 'Lenny'];

function addName() {
  var custname = document.getElementById('custname').value;
  arrNameList.push(custname);
}

function processArray() {
  let output = `Total names in array : ${arrNameList.length}<br/>`;
  let longestName = arrNameList.reduce((a, b) => a.length > b.length ? a : b);
  output += arrNameList.join('<br/>');
  output += `<br/>Longest name is ${longestName}`;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;

  return output;
}
```

```html
<input id="custname" />
<button onclick="addName()">Add</button>
<button onclick="processArray()">Process</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, from your code it doesnt seem like you are calling your functions anywhere, maybe that part of the code is missing in your question. In any case, here is how I would do it:

```
function process_array() {
    let longest = ''
    arrNameList.forEach((name) => {
        if (name.length > longest.length) {
            longest = name
        }
    })

    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'The names are ' + arrNameList.join(', ') + ' and the longest is ' + longest
}
```

You can iterate through an array with .[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=example) and what Im doing in that function is just replacing the one value for the longest word. Another *trick* Im using is to [join the elements of the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join?v=example)

### Edit

A more efficient way of finding the longest element in an array is with [sorting the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?v=example):

```
let longest = arrNameList.sort((a, b) => { 
    return b.length - a.length; 
})[0];
```

Comment: Sorry, my functions are being called with a HTML button. Actually, only the addName() function is being called. Everything else happens with js

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` to get the longest string in an array.

This is simply returning the length of the longest string in the reduction.

```js
var arrNameList = ['John', 'Lenny'];

console.log(
  arrNameList.reduce((longest, name) => Math.max(longest, name.length), 0)
)
```

Answer (score -1):

**your code is slightly wrong as you are comparing two string rather comparing the length of the string**.

**Replace this code**

```
var arrNameList = ['John', 'Lenny'];
var arrNameListLonger = [];

function addName() {
    var custname = document.getElementById('custname').value;
    arrNameList.push(custname);
}

function processArray() {
    var i = 0;
    var output = ('Total names in array is: ' + arrNameList.length + '<br />');
    while (i < arrNameList.length) {
        output += (arrNameList[i] + '<br />');
        if (arrNameList[i] > arrNameList[i + 1]) {
            arrNameListLonger[0] = (arrNameList[i]);
            output += ('The longest name in the array is ' + arrNameListLonger[0].length + ' characters');

        }
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
        i++;
    }
    return (output);
}

**by**

var arrNameList = ['John', 'Lenny'];
var arrNameListLonger = [];

function processArray() {
    var i = 0;

    var output = ('Total names in array is: ' + arrNameList.length + '<br />');
    while (i < arrNameList.length) {
        output += (arrNameList[i] + '<br />');

    if(i<arrNameList.length-1){
         if (arrNameList[i].length > arrNameList[i + 1].length) {
            arrNameListLonger[0] = (arrNameList[i]);


        }
        else{
             arrNameListLonger[0] = (arrNameList[i+1]);
        }


    }
        i++;
    }
    console.log(arrNameListLonger[0].length);
    return (output);
}
```